# How to open the pick dialog of ng-datetime-picker programmatically in Angular4/TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to open the ng date time (owl-date-time) picker dialog programmatically?

[date-time-picker](https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/) - *"Open Picker as a Dialog"* section.

html

```
<mat-select  [(ngModel)]="createAnnounceReq.sendStatus" formControlName="sendStatus" (change)="onChange_Status($event.value)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of sendStatusList; let i = index;" [value]="item.value">
        {{ item.label }}

        //dropdown is like
        - Today (Now)
        - 1week a head
        - 3 months a head
        - pick specific date

    </mat-option>
</mat-select>

<input [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt5" [owlDateTime]="dt5" readonly>
<owl-date-time [pickerMode]="'dialog'" #dt5></owl-date-time>
```

type-script

```
.....

@Component({
  selector: 'app-announce-send',
  templateUrl: './announce-send.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./announce-send.component.css'], 
  providers : [AnnourceService]
})
export class AnnounceSendComponent implements OnInit {  
    .....

    onChange_Status(value) {
        if(value == something) {
            // here how to open picker dialog programmatically
        }
    }

    .....   
}
```

Comment: You can try to simulate `click` event on the `input` element programmatically

Comment: @CommercialSuicide, yes. It is my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simulate `click` event programmatically, you can add identifier to your `input` element, and then get access to it inside the component, something like this:

HTML

```
<input #target [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt5" [owlDateTime]="dt5" readonly>
```

COMPONENT

```
@ViewChild('target') target: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  /* Simulate click event every 5 seconds */
  setInterval(() => this.target.nativeElement.click(), 5000);
}
```

And here is a live example of focusing the `input` programmatically (you can just replace `focus()` with `click()` event if needed):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1xz9zv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts